# Transparency problems when adding an overlay to an icon

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons, overlay

I've got an `.ico` file with a `.png` file that has an overlay I want to apply to the icon. I'm very inexperienced in this so managed to get bits of code off the internet until I had something that almost works.

The problem is that the transparency is lost and replaced with white.

Also, I think the range of colours is reduced.  I added some debug code (commented out) to save the icon at 2 stages. When I edit it at the first stage in VS 2010, the colour pallete has 16 colours, stage1.ico has many more.

Seems to be the `Icon.FromHandle` causing the problems. The function below takes two ImageSource parameters.  The first comes from the `.ico` file and the second from the `.png` file (overlay).

What should I be doing instead?

Function -

```
private static Icon Render(ImageSource baseImage, ImageSource overlay)
{
  int iconSize = 32;

  RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap
    = new RenderTargetBitmap(iconSize,
    iconSize,
    96, 96,
    PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

  DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
  using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
  {
    context.DrawImage(baseImage, new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize));
    context.DrawImage(overlay, new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize));
    context.Close();
    renderBitmap.Render(visual);
  }
  BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
  encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  encoder.Save(stream); 

  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
  //bmp.Save("c:\\tmp\\stage1.ico"); // save what we have here
  IntPtr Hicon = bmp.GetHicon();
  Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);
  // Looking at stage2.ico gives a different version to stage1.ico
  //using (var fs = new FileStream("c:\\tmp\\stage2.ico", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Delete))
  //{
    //icon.Save(fs);
  //}
  return icon;
}
```

Comment: The part that uses this icon is WinForms though I do invoke a WPF window later.  The WinForms part is displaying an icon in the system tray - it's this icon that's got the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: GetHicon() is the problem, it uses a pretty primitive algorithm.  It uses a palette with only 16 primary colors.  The result is invariably disappointing unless the image is very simple.  It is a hard problem, I don't know of any perfect solutions.

Comment: Well I suppose my option is to get the overlays applied by the guy who does icons and not try to do it in code.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an icon dynamically with transparency for use as an overlay icon with the code below. For my program I wanted a number displaying how many new messages were queued up. Pardon the VB...

```
Private _counter As Integer = 0

Public Sub NewMessageIncrementOverlay()
  _counter += 1
  Dim displayVal = If(_counter > 9, "+", _counter.ToString)

  Dim bitm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(40, 40,
                         System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
  Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitm)
  g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Transparent, 0, 0, 40, 40)
  g.FillPie(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 40, 40, 0, 360)
  g.DrawString(displayVal, New Font("Consolas", 30, FontStyle.Bold),
               System.Drawing.Brushes.White, New PointF(3, -5))

  If TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported Then
    Dim icon As Icon = icon.FromHandle(bitm.GetHicon)
    TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(icon, displayVal)
  End If
End Sub
```